# $sce:insecurl with local Url on v 1.2.9

Tags: angularjs, escaping, angularjs-ng-include

I have the following code:

```
<span ng-include="getHeaderTemplate()"></span>
```

getHeaderTemplate() returns "templates/header/prospection.html"

however, I get the following error:

```
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: templates/header/prospection.html
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$sce/insecurl?p0=templates%2Fheader%2Fprospection.html
    at http://localhost/piquick/laravel/public/vendor/angular-1.2.9.js:78:12
    at Object.getTrusted (http://localhost/piquick/laravel/public/vendor/angular-1.2.9.js:12739:17)
    at Object.sceParseAsTrusted (http://localhost/piquick/laravel/public/vendor/angular-1.2.9.js:13168:22)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost/piquick/laravel/public/vendor/angular-1.2.9.js:11800:40)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost/piquick/laravel/public/vendor/angular-1.2.9.js:12061:24)
    at http://localhost/piquick/laravel/public/vendor/angular-1.2.9.js:1302:15
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost/piquick/laravel/public/vendor/angular-1.2.9.js:3710:17)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost/piquick/laravel/public/vendor/angular-1.2.9.js:1300:14)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost/piquick/laravel/public/vendor/angular-1.2.9.js:1314:12)
    at angularInit (http://localhost/piquick/laravel/public/vendor/angular-1.2.9.js:1263:5)
```

The Url is on the same server (it's a local URL), so I don't understand why I get this error.

Here's the doc about $sce

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce#resourceurlpatternitem](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce#resourceurlpatternitem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like AngularJS' Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) mode has blocked loading a resource from an "insecure" URL.

Their docs state: "The browser's Same Origin Policy and Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) policy apply that may further restrict whether the template is successfully loaded. (e.g. neither cross-domain requests won't work on all browsers nor file:// requests on some browsers)"

Try wrapping the template url with a call like:

```
$sce.trustAsUrl('templates/header/prospection.html')
```

[Here's more info.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce#methods_trustasresourceurl)

Comment: I don't understand why the 'templates/header/prospection.html' doesn't fit the CORS. It's a local URL, so they shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: Not sure myself. I suppose there is some aspect of the browser's policy that off? Does my suggestion work, though?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me the same configuration. Can you please give us plnkr example?

Comment: They was some bad code there on my file: `m.config(['$sceDelegateProvider',function($sceDelegateProvider) {
 $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['.*']);
}]);`. It was just that.

Comment: @edi9999 could you please explain in more detail how you resolved this issue? For example, which file contained the error?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I don't remember what was wrong here, been a long time (18months)